# npm: how to decode a CSR using javascript/npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, csr

Is there a possibility to decode the CSR to expose the typcial fields like CN, OU, O, etc. in javascript? I cannot find a npm-package.

I know the **openssl** program, that is able to extract this information. But in my case the CSR is forwarded to a CA through javascript. It should onlybe fowarded to the CA, if the OU-field contains a specific name unless it gets revoked by the CA.

```
csr.getAttribute({name: 'commonName'}); //returns ""
```

Does not work in my case. The result is an empty string.

I guess my provided CSR (with this usual format -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----...) as a string, I pass to this method is not what is perfectly expected by this function:

```
var csr = forge.pki.certificationRequestFromPem(csr);
```

But still I managed to access the **commonName** subject by going through the array of objects:

```
var csrDecrypted = forge.pki.certificationRequestFromPem(csr);
var subjects = csrDecrypted.subject.attributes;
var commonName = subjects.find(function(subject) {
       return subject["name"] === "commonName";
}).value;  //returns "MyCommonName"
```

Now, I need to make sure the provided CSR is valid. If I corrupt the CSR string by adding some nonesense the following method crashes:

```
var csr = forge.pki.certificationRequestFromPem(csr);
```

and I cannot call:

```
csr.verify()
```

How can I detect, if a CSR is corrupt (like it doesn't follow PKS#10 format e.g.), without crashing?

Comment: Your question has changed significantly. It is recommended to post a new one because it can invalidate the answers provided. In this case my answer does not make sense

Comment: @pedrofb your answer was pretty useful so far. At least I was able to extract the subject commonName. To figure out, if the CSR string has a valid format, I simply wrapped the **forge.pki.certificationRequestFromPem(csr)** method  by a try/catch method. So I see implicitly, when an excepction gets fired I know, it must have been the wrong format. otherwise it had the right format.